# Excel Power Query integration with Salesforce: The Service Returned an invalid token

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, power-query, salesforce

I have set up Salesforce integration in Excel to pull data from some of my reports to a spreadsheet.
After a Microsoft Windows Update (I suppose) my excel integration stopped working returning an Authentication error: "The Service Returned an invalid token".
[image]
I have found old articles written in 2016 that describe a very similar issue which concluded the issue related to the fact that Excel 2016 was initiating TLS 1.0 connection while Salesforce required newer TLS 1.2. The old issue can be fixed by forcing Windows to work with TLS 1.2 by default with editing system registry or environment variable. [Article 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2013_release/excel-power-query-can-no-longer-connect-to/d4bd7092-c34b-4307-a844-958011c359dd). [Article 2](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000p9Y1QAI).
I have checked my Login History for my user and found out that all the longings from Excel were always initiated using TLS 1.2 and actually return login Success, therefore TLS 1.0 issue and fix is not applicable for my case.

What seems to be an issue and how to fix it?

Login History

```
Id,                 Status,                 TlsProtocol,            ApiType, ApiVersion, Application, AuthenticationServiceId, Browser, ClientVersion, LoginGeoId, LoginTime, LoginType, LoginUrl, OptionsIsGet, OptionsIsPost, Platform, SourceIp, UserId
00000000000000002   Success                 TLS 1.2 N/A Browser     IE 11 (Compatibility View)  N/A 04F00000iDOMUAO 2050-55-77T16:40:20.000Z    Remote Access Client    login.salesforce.com    false   false   Windows 10  111.111.111.111 055555555555555555
00000000000000001   Multi-factor required   TLS 1.2 N/A Browser     IE 11 (Compatibility View)  N/A 04F00000iDOMUAO 2050-55-77T16:40:10.000Z    Remote Access Client    login.salesforce.com    false   false   Windows 10  111.111.111.111 055555555555555555
```

- Windows 10 x64 Professional 20H2 OS Build 19042.685
- Microsoft 365 Excel version 2011 (Build 13426.20308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The troubleshooting section in this document might be relevant:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/salesforceobjects#troubleshooting

In summary:

- install Edge Chromium
- in System Environment Variables set PQ_ExtendEdgeChromiumOAuthAllowList to Salesforce

Comment: Thanks so much, it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You likely have too many connections in your OAuth Connected apps. Go to the user setup page for the user account you are trying to log in with and scroll down to OAuth Connected Apps. Then, revoke all tokens for power query. Now you should be able to log into SFDC in power query.